# How to insert application package name with manifestmerger?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Let me start out with the manifest line:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.sample.library.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.sample.library" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This example line above is sitting inside the AndroidManifest in an Android library project.
I also have an application project that has a package name: **com.my.sample.application**.

When manifestmerger is enabled inside this application project, the manifestmerger literally copies over the above line. Meaning that the category will be pointing to the wrong package name.

Is there a way to tell the manifestmerger to insert it's application package name?